# Removing carriage return character ^M from output file created by python script

Tags: python, linux, carriage-return

I have a python script that outputs file with similar text:

```
1234\insert into\\default\e72303\FINISHED\False\23ms\N/A\37m10s\105\2017-
08-23 09:55:10.155407000\2017-08-23 09:55:10.178453000
```

This data is split by "\" and is imported to a table in hive database.

My issue that some of that data contains ^M carriage return character which splits up my data:

```
1234\INSERT INTO customer_touch.XXX_test_data_pickup^M
(^M
    CI\default\e72303\FINISHED\False\331ms\0 / 0 ( 0%)\37m11s\0\2017-08-
23 09:55:08.066620000\2017-08-23 09:55:08.398299000
```

I need to remove ^M and have my data all together. I have tried dos2unix on the filename which does remove ^M but my data is still split.

Below is my code. I have crontab setup that outputs this into a text file

```
datanodes = ["https://XXXXXXX/",
             "https://XXXXXXX"]                

for i, datanode in enumerate(datanodes):
   try:
       response = requests.get(datanode + "queries?
json",auth=HTTPDigestAuth(XXX, XXX),verify='XXXX.pem')
    data = response.json()
    for query in data['completed_queries']:
        print query['query_id'] + "\\" + query['stmt'][0:80] + "\\" + query['default_db'] + "\\" + query['effective_user'] + "\\" + query['state'] + "\\"  + str(query['executing']) + "\\" + query['duration'] + "\\" + query['progress'] + "\\" + query['waiting_time'] + "\\" + str(query['rows_fetched']) + "\\" + query['start_time']+ "\\" + query['end_time']

except IOError as ioe:
    print ioe
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: You haven't posted the code that produces the file.

Comment: I have a crontab setup that outputs this into a text file

Comment: Why don't you clean your data so it doesn't contain those pesky carriage returns? You're just printing it indiscriminately...

Comment: BTW, in Python land those characters are written as `'\r'`.

Comment: ...so, they can be removed with, f/e, `query['stmt'].replace('\r', '')`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that did the trick. My data still splits up on a new line if there is a "(" in the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Not without a proper [mcve] so we can test our answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to remove ^M with replace('\r', '') per Charles Duffy's suggestion. I changed my code to query['stmt'][0:80].replace('\r', '')

Answer (score 0):

Put a `| tr -d \r` at the end of your cron job.

https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html